# struts2 - how to access an image present inside a war/image folder from an action class?

Tags: struts2, struts

I have an image present inside the `images` folder of my `war`, and my action class is at `war/WEB-INF/classes/some_package`. I wish to access that image inside my action class. I believe I can do it by using `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream("images/my_image.png")` (as it takes the war folder as the base), but is there a more direct way of doing that in `Struts2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is how you access class path resources, which is unrelated to Struts.

You may use a ["stream" result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html) to send it back to the client, however.